# 404:Not Found error when running Jupyter Notebooks on Microsoft Azure HDInsight 3.5

Tags: azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, azure-hdinsight

I have deployed a HDInsight 3.5 Spark (2.0) cluster on Microsoft Azure with the standard configurations (Location = US East, Head Nodes = D12 v2 (x2), Worker Nodes = D4 v2 (x4)). When the cluster is running, I click Jupyter Notebook in "Cluster Dashboards" quick link. After entering my username and password in the prompt, I receive a page giving me a 404: Not Found page. More specific the the following (json) message is shown:

{
  "status": 404,
  "message": "Not Found"
}

(This is in Google Chrome. In Internet page a similar, but differently looking, page 404 error page is shown.)

Cloud somebody help me with this error?

Answer (score 1):

There's an undergoing issue preventing from Jupyter to work as expected out of the box on HDInsight at the moment.
You can still use other deployment methods until this is resolved.

Edit: For example, you can run Jupyter locally and connect to the HDI cluster in Azure. See
https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/README.md#installation
and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-install-locally

**Update: Issue was fixed**

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you know when this issue will be resolved (hours, days, weeks, months, etc.)? Is there an alternative way to use a notebook on the HDInsight cluster? Zeppelin is not available, installing jupyter notebook locally (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-install-locally), and using SSH all don't seem to work.

Comment: can you provide more information/links about the issue?

Comment: Sorry but this is all I have.. It is a temporal issue and will be resolved soon. I don't know when, I am waiting for the fix as well.

Comment: @StijnGeuens I do run Jupyter locally and connect to the HDI cluster in Azure. It's working well, I've updated my answer to reflect that. Use this doc: https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/README.md#installation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have installed sparkmagic and I am able to chose the PySpark kernel. Even tough I get the message that the kernel is ready, when I try to execute a simple statement (e.g. t = 4), the kernel starts to run infinitely. Could you provide possible solution(s).

Answer (score 1):

Running the following via SSH will solve the issue:

```
echo "c.NotebookApp.token = ''" | sudo tee --append /var/lib/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py > /dev/null
sudo pkill -f jupyter-notebook
```

It fixes the config file and then kills the jupyter process. Ambari will then take a minute or so to notice that Jupyter is no longer running and restart the service, which will pick up the new config.

These commands are being run on live clusters at the moment to fix the bug.

Comment: To connect to the head nodes, use CLUSTERNAME-ssh.azurehdinsight.net, where CLUSTERNAME is the name of the HDInsight cluster. Connecting on port 22 (the default for SSH) connects to the primary head node. Port 23 connects to the secondary head node.

To connect to an edge node, use EDGENAME.CLUSTERNAME-ssh.azurehdinsight.net, where EDGENAME is the name of the edge node and CLUSTERNAME is the name of the HDInsight cluster. Use port 22 when connecting to the edge node.

Comment: This solution works. Although I prefer a "cleaner" solution.Thanks